# Sorting DataTables in datetime format

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatables

i have a column that the data is in date time, like **03/18/2016 10:53:00 AM**, whenever im sorting it, it doesnt sort properly...

[image]

```
$date = $row->Status_ == 'RELEASED'? date("m/d/Y h:i:s A",strtotime($row->Released_Date)) : date("m/d/Y",strtotime($comDate));
$dateOrder = $row->Status_ == 'RELEASED'? strtotime($row->Released_Date) : strtotime($comDate);

$list .= "<tr class='gradeX'>
            <td class='center' data-order='".$dateOrder."'>
                <b title='View committed date' class='titleCommit' data-item='".$itemCode."'>".$date."</b>
            </td>
```

im sorting it in **DESCENDING**

Comment: It looks to be sorting correctly when each value is taken as a string. For a sortable date format, use the ISO date format, which looks like this: 2016-03-17 19:44:33. Due to its arrangement, when sorted as a date or a string format, the sort will be accurate.

Comment: yeah i know, it sort as string, can u tell me how can i sort it even if thats the format ill you? thnx for the reply :)

Comment: Do you have any code to post for us to take a look at? And/or a var_dump of the data being used to build the table in your view? Conceptually what you will want to do is for each row, convert the date to a sortable format (`strtotime($current_date)` should be sufficient), and then in your view as you construct your rows, convert the date back to the format you need to display.

Comment: i update my question...

Comment: Is the ordering happening in JavaScript dynamically (and perhaps the user can click to switch the sort) as opposed to the ordering happening in PHP and then being sent to the page already ordered?

Comment: If you are using [**jQuery dataTables**](https://datatables.net/) (it is not so clear?) then you have to set the `type` for the column i.e.     `{ type: 'date' `}, it should be able to handle the described datetime format - otherwise use a sorting plugin.

Answer (score 0):

A custom sorting function should do what you want. If you include momentjs this is really easy:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "dom-date-pre": function(a) {
        return moment(a, "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss A")
    },
    "dom-date-asc": function(a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },
    "dom-date-desc": function(a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
});
```

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/n3r4y9hs/) with your data.